# Find the rate at which r is changing, when $ t=4$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Starting from a point $O$, a particle $P$ moves due north such that its displacement (in meters) from $O$ is given by $y=40t$, where $t$ is in seconds.

Also starting from $O$, a particle $Q$ moves due east such that its displacement from $O$ is given buy $x=t^2$

Let $r$ be the distance between the two particles at $4$ seconds for $t$

Find the rate at which $r$ is changing.

So since to find the rate, you get the first derivative, I get

$y=40$,
$x=2t$

which becomes

$y=40$ , 
$x=8$

$40/8 = 5$ units per second

Is that the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the Cartesian plane . Let us assume  point $O$ to lie on origin , $P$ to lie on $Y$ Axis and $Q$ to lie on $X$ Axis.

At a time $t$ , coordinates of $P$ is given by $(0,40t)$ and the  coordinates of $Q$ is given by $(t^2 , 0)$.

Distance between these two points is $D = \sqrt{(40t-0)^2 +(0-t^2)^2}$

$$D = \sqrt{1600t^2 + t^4}$$

Then the rate of change of distance is :

$$\begin{align}\frac{d(D)}{dt} & = \frac{d\left(\sqrt{1600t^2 + t^4}\right)}{dt} \\ 
\frac{d(D)}{dt} & = \frac{\left({1600 + 2t^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\left({1600 + t^2}\right)}} \end{align}$$

At $t=4$ , the rate of change of distance is :
$$r = \frac{1632}{\sqrt{1616}}$$

Or $$r \approx 40.5975$$.

Comment: Check your derivative of the term inside the radical when you applied the Chain Rule.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig [Wolfram Aplha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+%28%5Csqrt%7B1600t%5E2+%2B+t%5E4%7D%29) agrees with my answer.

Comment: No, it does not.  Notice that there is a $t$ outside the parentheses.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig And there is a $t^2$ inside the square root in the denominator

Comment: You have a quadratic in your numerator, while Wolfram Alpha has a cubic.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig [See this.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282+t+%28800+%2B+t%5E2%29%29%2Fsqrt%28t%5E2+%281600+%2B+t%5E2%29%29+at+t+%3D4) Unforutnately  , I don't see the problem still.

Comment: I see.  You canceled the $t$ in the numerator with the $t^2$ in the radical.  I should have looked at your denominator more carefully.  That said, if I missed that, somebody who is just learning calculus may have a hard time seeing how you obtained the derivative since you omitted the steps.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Understandable . The reason I specifically omitted the derivative part is so that the O.P could try himself to get that and not entirely depend upon others to solve the question for him .

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit thank you for your help, I appreciate that you didn't give me the correct answer without me learning how to do it.Thanks